# Do I need to implement NSManagedObjectContext Notifications when using multiple CoreData NSManagedObjectContexts?

Tags: iphone, ios, caching, core-data, concurrency

I currently have 2 contexts in my app. My app uses multiple tabs so one tab could be displaying data whilst another tab might be in data entry mode.

There is one main context I use to read most of the data for display. When I insert data I am using a second temporary context as I don't want the operation of other tabs to save possibly incomplete objects added to the context.

I have been reading apples concurrency guide:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW1

It indicates that you should use notifications to propagate changes between contexts.

**Both of my contexts use the same propagation store object. My question is if a change is made to context A in tab A, when a fetch request is reissued in tab B using context B will the changes simply show up in tab B?**

This is what I am seeing at the moment. I assume core data caching is done at the propogation store level? If thats correct then synchronizing contexts is only required where you don't intend to re run a fetch query so you can selectively update only the NSManagedObjects that have changed?

This is how I am getting my new context:

```
   NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    NSManagedObjectContext *newContext;
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        newContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [newContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Changes you make to a managed object in one context are not propagated to a corresponding managed object in a different context unless you either refetch or re-fault the object."

Answer (score 1):

If you want the data that you modify in Tab B to show up in Tab A (and vise versa) when you are using two different NSManagedObjectContexts you need to add an observer to the notification

`NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`

in the controller code for Tab A (and B if changes are being made in A)

as in

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(mergeChanges:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:nil];
```

Then at the declared selector

```
-(void)mergeChanges:(NSNotification *)anotif
{
    [self.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:anotif];
    [self updateTheUI];
}
```

Comment: In tab B if i just reissue the fetch request that encompasses object(s) from tab A I see the new data. This is why I was wondering if apples recommendation is only if you want to selectively update existing NSManagedObjects already in your context as it looks like a fetch request reloads them anyway. I just wanted to be sure that this was the behaviour.

Comment: If you are using NSFetchedResultsController the code above is done for you automagically I think. Otherwise you shouldnt be seeing changes in  context A in context B until you merge explicitly as above. Do you really have 2 unique MOC objects?

Comment: Im not using NSFetchedResultsController I have edited the code post to show how I am instantiating the new context. All contexts use the same persistance store coordinator object.

Comment: ahah! "Changes you make to a managed object in one context are not propagated to a corresponding managed object in a different context unless you either refetch or re-fault the object." Must have skipped over that bit, exactly as i thought, thanks for the help.